# Multidimensional arrays and user data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array

### AND THE DISPLAY FRIENDS FUNCTION MENTIONED IN THE NEXT FUNCTION

```
 function displayfriends($major, $friends) {
    // Whatever markup you want here
    // For example -- unordered list
if (count($friends) > 0) {
echo "<h2>Friends with $major major</h2>";
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    echo "<li>$friend</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

}
}

THIS IS A TEST FUNCTION TO WORK WITH THE UI

```
 function getFriendsWithMajor($major) {
 $config = array(
 'appId' => '',
 'secret' => '',
 );
 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 try {
 $fql    =   "select uid,name,education from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
 $param  =   array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => $fql,
 'callback'  => ''
 );
 $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
 } catch(Exception $o) {
    d($o);
 }

 $friends = $fqlResult;
 $friends_BA = array();

 foreach ($friends as $friend) {
     if (is_array($friend['education'])) {
         foreach ($friend['education'] as $school) {
             if (isset($school['concentration'])) {
                foreach ($school['concentration'] as $concentration) {
                    if (strpos(strtolower($concentration['name']), $major) !== false) {
                        $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                        continue 3; // skip to the next friend
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
$this->displayfriends($major);
```

}

Here's the output I'm getting:
Warning: Missing argument 2 for social::displayfriends(), called in /home/content/07/8316707/html/class.Social.php on line 234 and defined in /home/content/07/8316707/html/class.Social.php on line 183

Keep in mind, when I did $this->displayfriends($major, $friends) it only returned one result when it should have returned 15.

Comment: I'm not clear on A.  What is the variable for major? Is 'concentration' the same as major here?  This code filters for people with a business major.  Are you just trying to get all people, and store/display their major?

Comment: trying to get a list of the active users friends who meet certain criteria, same college, major, current location, etc. Concentration is major, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're looking for.  You basically just need to understand php arrays, and how to use parameters with functions.  print_r is a debugging tool that generates the output you see.  For use of your array data, you should handle it directly.  Simplest way is to foreach through it.  I made a separate function for the display just to reinforce both concepts.

```
function getFriendsWithMajor($major) {
     $config = array(
     'appId' => 'XXXXXXX',
     'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
     );
     $facebook = new Facebook($config);
     $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
     try {
     $fql    =   "select uid,name,education from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user_id))";
     $param  =   array(
     'method'    => 'fql.query',
     'query'     => $fql,
     'callback'  => ''
     );
     $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
     } catch(Exception $o) {
        d($o);
     }

     $friends = $fqlResult;
     $friends_BA = array();

     foreach ($friends as $friend) {
         if (is_array($friend['education'])) {
             foreach ($friend['education'] as $school) {
                 if (isset($school['concentration'])) {
                    foreach ($school['concentration'] as $concentration) {
                        if (strpos(strtolower($concentration['name']), $major) !== false) {
                            $friends_BA[] = $friend['name'];
                            continue 3; // skip to the next friend
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    displayfriends($major, $friends_BA);
}
```

Display function

```
function displayfriends($major, $friends) {
        // Whatever markup you want here
        // For example -- unordered list
  if (count($friends) > 0) {
    echo "<h2>Friends with $major major</h2>";
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($friends as $friend) {
        echo "<li>$friend</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

Calling the functions:

```
getFriendsWithMajor('**business**);
getFriendsWithMajor('**marketing**);
```

Comment: I'm having some issues with the code. I'm getting these errors: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/07/8316707/html/class.Social.php on line 220

Fatal error: Call to undefined function displayfriends() in /home/content/07/8316707/html/class.Social.php on line 234

Comment: If these functions are really methods in a class, then they have to be called as $this->displayfriends(..) inside the getFreindsWithMajor method.

Comment: Now it's missing arguments for Display Friends function.

Comment: Would have to see your code at this point.  The params were baked into the code I provided.

Comment: You neglected to pass the array into the display_friends method.  Needless to say that without the array, the display method isn't going to do anything.  Needs to be 
$this->displayfriends($major, $friends_BA);